# Hiding a UITabBar programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a UITabBar which controls multiple Views and I would like to hide one of them from the release build, but still keeping it in the project as I need it for testing purposes. How can I do this programmatically? It should not be visible to the user at all. Thanks!

Comment: What is a TabView? Do you mean a UITabBar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this. Try `[yourTabBar setHidden:YES];` also `[yourTabBar setAlpha:0];`

One other best thing I do, if you are using Interface builder to develop your UI is to move the appropriate `UIView` (here its `UITabBar`). out of the main `nib` (or `xib`) file. That way you are hiding whatever view you want to hide & at the same time it's part of the build.

Answer (score 0):

After the tabBar is initialized do the following:

```
NSMutableArray* currentItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tabBar.viewControllers];
[currentItems removeObjectAtIndex:itemNumberToRemove];
[tabBar setViewControllers:currentItems animated:NO];
```

What this does:

It gets the current viewcontrollers held by the UITabBar, removes an item from the array specified by itemNumberToRemove and then puts the items remaining back in the UITabBar.